# Interact with bluetooth ble UHF RFID Scanner using Flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rfid

First of all sorry for the poor English, there goes the question...

My friend bought a UHF RFID scanner device ([this model](http://www.chafon.com/productdetails.aspx?pid=602)) and the challenge is to make a Flutter app to interact with the scanner functions like scanning tags, setting up the scanning range etc.

The manufacturer even provides a sample project for native android, delphi and C# language with all the functionalities working; there's also a .dll sdk which could make development easier in some way.

It's kind of a new subject for me, I did some research about how interact with ble devices but this RFID thing seem more complicated, I know I have to send write/read commands to specific services/characteristics to get the desired response.

My main goal is to be able to trigger the scanning mode and retrieve a list with the scanned tags and the possibilities I crossed throught that could help me get on the way to achieve this goal seems to be as follows:

1.) "Merge" the SDK .dll that the manufacturer provides with a Flutter project to call the functions, it even comes with a guide with all the functions explained, link here [UHFReader816UBT.DLL Dynamic Link Library](https://ufile.io/gm0ryowe);

2.) Use the Android Native project that the manufacturer provided as a Flutter plugin or something like it so I could call the not-native libraries built with Java for each function available for the scanning device, [the java project sample goes here](https://ufile.io/izaojl5m).

All I was able to do by myself so far was the BLE device connection with [Flutter Blue package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) and get the services and characteristics of it but couldn't do much more.

I'm not sure if I gave all the details but there's also an overall manual provided by the scanner manufacturers, [here's the link](https://ufile.io/a676p3mo), if in order to get the desired results with this scanner I'll have to build all the command data blocks with CRC calculations, lenght, byte data and other stuff alongside with the logical steps in order to operate correctly (first triggering the scan command for X time, second retrieve the data collected etc.), then I'll have a whole new field to study and get to learn, but I'm a 100% up to it.

Thanks.

---- Device info
Device Model - Chafon CF-H301

Comment: It seems like you are on the right track. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I think that the way to go is find a way to "merge" the java sample project provided by the scanner manufacturer, i'm still unsure of how to do it, i only found tutorials about how to invoke native java code into a flutter project, but these are custom libraries

Comment: Custom libraries written in native java. This should work the same way

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels